# Is there a way to programmatically give focus to another running application in OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a use case where I'd like my app to give focus to a specific running application.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the application's bundle id (and only need to target 10.6+), you can do:

```
NSRunningApplicatin *app = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.foo.someapp"];
[app activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateAllWindows];
```

Answer (score 3):

Just send a chunk of AppleScript from your app, e.g.

```
tell application "Some other app"
    activate
end tell
```

Comment: @Wayne: OK - it might be a good idea to state this requirement in the question then.

Answer (score 0):

If the other app has registered a custom URL scheme, you can launch it by submitted a URL with that scheme.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, my answer was for iOS apps (doh!).